# Reader is running only once

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have a batch job in which I have a step which fetches and stores information regarding each country on a list of countries. I have used partition job but I was asked not to use it. Is there any approach we can use through which we can accomplish this same behaviour?

My job configuration is as follows

```
  private Job batchJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get(jobName)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(jobFlow())
                .end()
                .build();
      }

private JobExecutionDecider jobExecutionDecider(CountryConfig countryConfig) {

     return new JobExecutionDecider() {
       @Override
       public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution, StepExecution stepExecution) {
         System.out.println("JED: status: "+ (countryConfig.hasNextCountry() ? new FlowExecutionStatus("CONTINUE") : new FlowExecutionStatus("FINISHED")));
         return countryConfig.hasNextCountry() ? new FlowExecutionStatus("CONTINUE") : new FlowExecutionStatus("FINISHED");
       }
     };
  }

      private Flow jobFlow() {
        SimpleFlow simpleFlow = new SimpleFlow(jobName + "_flow");
        List<StateTransition> transitions = new LinkedList<>();
        transitions.add(StateTransition.createStateTransition(new StepState(step()), "decision"));
        transitions.add(StateTransition.createStateTransition(new DecisionState(jobExecutionDecider(countryConfig()), "decision"), "CONTINUE", stepName ));
        transitions.add(StateTransition.createEndStateTransition(new DecisionState(jobExecutionDecider(countryConfig()), "decision"), "*"));
        simpleFlow.setStateTransitions(transitions);
        return simpleFlow;
      }
      protected Step step() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get(stepName)
                .allowStartIfComplete(true)
                .<SiloNavTreeReaderResponse, SiloNavTreeProcessorResponse>chunk(1)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer())
                .build();
      }
```